# Return custom query with columns and a list that contains other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table structure

```
CREATE TABLE md 
(
    laborOfficeId NVARCHAR(2),
    sequenceNumber NVARCHAR(12),
    unifiedNationalNumber NVARCHAR(MAX),
    nationalId NVARCHAR(MAX) not null,
    paidStatus NVARCHAR(3) not null, -- Assuming Yes/No as values
    bankName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Iban NVARCHAR(MAX),
    WPSalary NVARCHAR(MAX), -- Assuming it's a decimal value
    paidYearMonth CHAR(6) not null, -- Assuming the format is fixed as YYYYMM
    deductionAmount NVARCHAR(MAX), -- Assuming it's a decimal value
    deduction NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO md (laborOfficeId, sequenceNumber, unifiedNationalNumber, nationalId, paidStatus, bankName, Iban, WPSalary, paidYearMonth, deductionAmount, deduction)
VALUES 
('1', '123456', '70023455436', '1143575354', 'yes', 'alrajhi', 'SA4420000422608010555321', '5000.00', '202401', '73.00', 'Absents'),
('1', '123456', '70023455436', '1143575354', 'yes', 'alrajhi', 'SA4420000422608010555321', '5000.00', '202402', '73.00', 'Absents'),
('1', '123456', '70023455436', '1143575354', 'yes', 'alrajhi', 'SA4420000422608010555321', '5000.00', '202403', '73.00', 'Absents');


SELECT * FROM md
```

[image]

I want to write a SQL query to return a different result

to return

```
laborOfficeId,
sequenceNumber,
unifiedNationalNumber,
nationalId
```

with a list of paidstatuslist which are an array of an objects contains other table column (paidStatus, bankName, Iban, WPSalary, paidYearMonth, deductionAmount, deduction)

If I query the main table, these columns are repeated with the same value where the list are different data

I searched for a solution found that this could happen using data tables insert and retrieve from it

Comment: If your table needs *seven* columns that contains over 4,000 characters each, I would really suggest you have some design issues.

Comment: Please do not use images for data, use table markdown

Comment: Please show an actual example of the results you wish to obtain - text descriptions are a poor way to describe data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FOR XML PATH('') to concatenate the column values for each row into a single string. Just to clarify the .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') will make sure that the result is treated as plain text if you are avoiding XML formatting

```
CREATE TABLE md (
        laborOfficeId NVARCHAR(2),
        sequenceNumber NVARCHAR(12),
        unifiedNationalNumber NVARCHAR(MAX),
        nationalId NVARCHAR(MAX) not null,
        paidStatus NVARCHAR(3) not null, -- Assuming Yes/No as values
        bankName NVARCHAR(MAX),
        Iban NVARCHAR(MAX),
        WPSalary NVARCHAR(MAX), -- Assuming it's a decimal value
        paidYearMonth CHAR(6) not null, -- Assuming the format is fixed as YYYYMM
        deductionAmount NVARCHAR(MAX), -- Assuming it's a decimal value
        deduction NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );
```

```
    INSERT INTO md (laborOfficeId, sequenceNumber, unifiedNationalNumber, nationalId, paidStatus, bankName, Iban, WPSalary, paidYearMonth, deductionAmount, deduction)
    VALUES 
    ('1', '123456', '70023455436', '1143575354', 'yes', 'alrajhi', 'SA4420000422608010555321', '5000.00', '202401', '73.00', 'Absents')
    ,
    ('1', '123456', '70023455436', '1143575354', 'yes', 'alrajhi', 'SA4420000422608010555321', '5000.00', '202402', '73.00', 'Absents')
    ,
    ('1', '123456', '70023455436', '1143575354', 'yes', 'alrajhi', 'SA4420000422608010555321', '5000.00', '202403', '73.00', 'Absents')
    ;
```

```
3 rows affected
```

```
SELECT * FROM md
```

| laborOfficeId | sequenceNumber | unifiedNationalNumber | nationalId | paidStatus | bankName | Iban | WPSalary | paidYearMonth | deductionAmount | deduction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | 70023455436 | 1143575354 | yes | alrajhi | SA4420000422608010555321 | 5000.00 | 202401 | 73.00 | Absents |
| 1 | 123456 | 70023455436 | 1143575354 | yes | alrajhi | SA4420000422608010555321 | 5000.00 | 202402 | 73.00 | Absents |
| 1 | 123456 | 70023455436 | 1143575354 | yes | alrajhi | SA4420000422608010555321 | 5000.00 | 202403 | 73.00 | Absents |

```
SELECT 
    laborOfficeId,
    sequenceNumber,
    unifiedNationalNumber,
    nationalId,
    (SELECT 
        paidStatus, 
        bankName,
        Iban,
        WPSalary,
        paidYearMonth,
        deductionAmount,
        deduction 
     FROM md AS md2
     WHERE md2.laborOfficeId = md.laborOfficeId 
       AND md2.sequenceNumber = md.sequenceNumber 
       AND md2.unifiedNationalNumber = md.unifiedNationalNumber 
       AND md2.nationalId = md.nationalId
     FOR JSON PATH) AS paidStatusList
FROM md
GROUP BY laborOfficeId, sequenceNumber, unifiedNationalNumber, nationalId;
```

| laborOfficeId | sequenceNumber | unifiedNationalNumber | nationalId | paidStatusList |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | 70023455436 | 1143575354 | [{"paidStatus":"yes","bankName":"alrajhi","Iban":"SA4420000422608010555321","WPSalary":"5000.00","paidYearMonth":"202401","deductionAmount":"73.00","deduction":"Absents"},{"paidStatus":"yes","bankName":"alrajhi","Iban":"SA4420000422608010555321","WPSalary":"5000.00","paidYearMonth":"202402","deductionAmount":"73.00","deduction":"Absents"},{"paidStatus":"yes","bankName":"alrajhi","Iban":"SA4420000422608010555321","WPSalary":"5000.00","paidYearMonth":"202403","deductionAmount":"73.00","deduction":"Absents"}] |

```
SELECT 
    laborOfficeId,
    sequenceNumber,
    unifiedNationalNumber,
    nationalId,
    (SELECT 
        paidStatus + ', ' + 
        bankName + ', ' + 
        Iban + ', ' + 
        WPSalary + ', ' + 
        paidYearMonth + ', ' + 
        deductionAmount + ', ' + 
        deduction + '; '
     FROM md AS md2
     WHERE md2.laborOfficeId = md.laborOfficeId 
       AND md2.sequenceNumber = md.sequenceNumber 
       AND md2.unifiedNationalNumber = md.unifiedNationalNumber 
       AND md2.nationalId = md.nationalId
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS paidStatusList
FROM md
GROUP BY laborOfficeId, sequenceNumber, unifiedNationalNumber, nationalId;
```

| laborOfficeId | sequenceNumber | unifiedNationalNumber | nationalId | paidStatusList |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | 70023455436 | 1143575354 | yes, alrajhi, SA4420000422608010555321, 5000.00, 202401, 73.00, Absents; yes, alrajhi, SA4420000422608010555321, 5000.00, 202402, 73.00, Absents; yes, alrajhi, SA4420000422608010555321, 5000.00, 202403, 73.00, Absents; |

```
SELECT 
    laborOfficeId,
    sequenceNumber,
    unifiedNationalNumber,
    nationalId,
    (SELECT 
        paidStatus + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 
        bankName + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 
        Iban + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 
        WPSalary + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 
        paidYearMonth + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 
        deductionAmount + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 
        deduction   + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
     FROM md AS md2
     WHERE md2.laborOfficeId = md.laborOfficeId 
       AND md2.sequenceNumber = md.sequenceNumber 
       AND md2.unifiedNationalNumber = md.unifiedNationalNumber 
       AND md2.nationalId = md.nationalId
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS paidStatusList
FROM md
GROUP BY laborOfficeId, sequenceNumber, unifiedNationalNumber, nationalId;
```

| laborOfficeId | sequenceNumber | unifiedNationalNumber | nationalId | paidStatusList |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | 70023455436 | 1143575354 | yes alrajhi SA4420000422608010555321 5000.00 202401 73.00 Absents yes alrajhi SA4420000422608010555321 5000.00 202402 73.00 Absents yes alrajhi SA4420000422608010555321 5000.00 202403 73.00 Absents |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wz5vBET-)

Comment: thanks for your detailed help if i want to save the paidStatusList as a string rather than json what should i do ,
is applicaple to save the paidStatusList in another new table and show its values in this column
@Amira Bedhiafi

Comment: In which format ? the values seperated by comma for examole ?

Comment: in any appropriate format for string or it should sent as a json , thanks again

Comment: if i want to insert anew line after every row after this : i tried add CHAR(10) but doesn't work

Comment: in sql server management studio doesn]t understand the new line . the query worked but not shows in display

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat more efficient method than the other answer is instead of a self-join, just do a subquery selecting from the columns you already have, then aggregate that JSON using `STRING_AGG`.

```sql
SELECT 
    md.laborOfficeId,
    md.sequenceNumber,
    md.unifiedNationalNumber,
    md.nationalId,
    '[' + STRING_AGG(j.paidStatusList, ',') + ']' AS paidStatusList
FROM md
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        md.paidStatus, 
        md.bankName,
        md.Iban,
        CAST(md.WPSalary AS decimal(18,9) AS WPSalary,
        md.paidYearMonth,
        md.deductionAmount,
        CAST(md.deduction AS decimal(18,9) AS deduction
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) AS j(paidStatusList)
GROUP BY
  md.laborOfficeId,
  md.sequenceNumber,
  md.unifiedNationalNumber,
  md.nationalId;
```